# Is the term "Hot dog" a misnomer? If not, then what makes a term a misnomer?

Tags: etymology, food, etymological-fallacy

I recently engaged in a lively debate with a friend about whether the term "hot dog" qualifies as a misnomer. My argument stemmed from the fact that a hot dog doesn't actually contain dog meat. Instead, it's typically made from beef, pork, or a combination of meats. My friend argues that the term "hot dog" supposedly originates from a playful association with the dachshund sausage, given its resemblance to the dog breed and therefore, it shouldn't qualify as a misnomer.

While this may be true due to the term's roots in historical references, it still inaccurately portrays the contents of this food today with the lack of any canine involvement.

Comment: I know dogs are eaten in some parts of the world, but no Westerner would seriously think that a hot dog sausage might be made of dog meat.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer) which discusses typical characteristics of a misnomer, or done any other research?

Comment: dachshund, **little dog sausage**, German: https://www.hot-dog.org/culture/hot-dog-history So easy to find, really. Misnomers are not about how things are already named. Misnomers are misuses of existing words **per their definitions**.

Comment: No, *hot dog* is like *whirlybird,* but it really took off.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Some believe that wasn't always the case (ie possibly some Westerners actually did seriously think that a hot dog sausage might be made of dog meat). Some cultures do eat dog. And quality control isn't uniform.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Coincidentally, the 'Dictionary Corner' item in next week's _Radio Times_ is about the hot dog. Apparently 'dog' used to be a slang word for a sausage, a joke about fears that they _might_ contain dog meat!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, your comment raises an interesting side-question. Suppose, for the sake of argument, that some Westerners did think that, and that the term therefore started out as a misnomer. Would that mean that it continues to be a misnomer now (when nobody thinks that), or would regarding it as a misnomer now be a version of the etymological fallacy?

Comment: A word that already exists cannot be a misnomer. A misnomer is the **misuse** of word in a particular situation.

Comment: @Lambie All words (this of course does not include future neologisms) exist already.  // Oxford Languages has: << **misnomer**: a wrong or inaccurate name or designation.
"morning sickness is a misnomer for many women, since the nausea can occur any time during the day" >> But of course the term 'morning sickness' is totally idiomatic, generally acceptable. It's not wrong to use it; it has a less-than-accurate surface meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth An inaccurate term or designation in context, not in a dictionary or phrase book. "He was a monster is a misnomer; he was in fact a gentle human being."

Comment: Please add research showing dictionary definitions and any examples given that allow well-understood terms (both the meaning, and the fact that the term is widely understood to be not felicitous, like 'jellyfish' but unlike 'horned toads) to be included in the set of misnomers.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks "[W]hat makes a term a misnomer?"

Let's attempt a definition for "misnomer"

**A word or phrase, typically nominal, used in a manner that is significantly inapt, especially in situations where an essential aspect its definition is ignored or overlooked; the act of using a word or phrase in such a manner.**

> These roadside restaurants dotting Route 9, with neon signs offering "Fine dining", often serve reheated frozen entrees, passing them off as freshly prepared. "Fine dining" is a misnomer for the experience.
>
> The Department of Transportation used to display signs in areas where highway roadwork was causing major delays. These signs read "TEMPORARY INCONVENIENCE. PERMANENT IMPROVEMENT." To call the improvement "permanent" was a misnomer, for these same roads became congested again in only a few years as the number of cars on the road increased.

Comment: Right, misnomer is about **usage** not about a word per se.

Answer (score 0):

I think no -- it would have to be at least plausibly a dog. For comparison, the term koala bear is a misnomer because the name leads people to believe a koala is a bear. The term hot dog isn't misleading, it's just (apparently) unrelated to the meaning.

Comment: The definitions of 'misnomer' I've just looked at specify 'a wrong / unsuitable name'', not mentioning misleadingness. And quite a few lists of misnomers include 'hot dog'. One suggested etymology for the term is that people commonly believed that the thin sausages used contained dog meat, which would [hopefully] make the term certainly a misnomer.  It's best to add reasonable support to answers, Iris.

Comment: No, koala bear is an existing term. Calling a prime minister a premier might be considered a misnomer by some people.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the term "hot dog" for frankfurters is college slang, believed to be due to the belief that dog meat was used to create these types of sausages.

Since this wasn't true, it could be considered a misnomer. But since it's a slang term that has become an idiom that's not interpreted literally, I don't think anyone would really consider it a misnomer now.

Comment: That depends on how 'misnomer' is defined. Many lists can be found that include 'hot dog', using the '[at least superficially] inappropriately named' definition.

Comment: Sounds like folk etymology to me...Existing words are not misnomers, it is misuse of words that are.

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps. None of the online dictionaries I checked (including OED) explains the origin, but  the MacOS dictionary says "late 19th century: originally US college slang, probably influenced by a popular belief that the sausages contained dog meat." So at the time it was a misnomer, but it has become an established idiom.

Answer (score -1):

If the term is misleading and the **words** within the term doesn't resemble it's definition, then it is a misnomer. Take Rhode Island and Greenland for example. Rhode Island isn't an island and Greenland isn't green. Much like in your case, a hot dog isn't a dog.

Comment: [...the words within the term doesn't resemble?]

Comment: '**If** the term is misleading . . .' Is anybody likely to be misled by the term that is at issue here?